# List view returning identical item position and id

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get this listview to return the sqlite db _id for each row when long-pressed.

However this line

```
onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

is returning the 'position' in the list instead of the id.

I've run out of ideas... can somebody point an Android beginner in the right direction?

```
public class MySavedPlaces extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_saved_places);

    //Creating a List View
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MySavedPlaces.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    final ListView mylist=(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    String URL = "content://com.db.place/locations";
    Uri locations = Uri.parse(URL);
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(locations, null, null, null, "name");
    c.moveToFirst();

    if(c!=null){
    //If there are contents in the database
    do{
        String id=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        listItems.add(name);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    mylist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MySavedPlaces.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            adapter.add("Navigate...");
            adapter.add("Delete");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MySavedPlaces.this);
            builder.setTitle("whatever title "+id+ " "+position+" "+view.getId());
            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Positive"+item );
                    // item is the list item number - Navigate == 0, Delete == 1
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            // Return true to consume the click event
            return true;
          }

        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are not storing this value:

```
 String id=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

Try creating  list of objects that have id, name as properties and store those items in a ArrayList so you can easily get the items out of the ArrayList.

instead of this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(MySavedPlaces.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
```

use something like this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<DataBaseRowObject> adapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<DataBaseRowObject>(MySavedPlaces.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
```

and to get the data out on ItemLongClickListener:

```
DataBaseRowObject selected = listItems.get(position);
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance - your advice got me up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with list adapter which must implement 4 methods getcount the number of views in the list. Get item, the child at a particular index listview. Getview the inflated child.and last but not least get index which you need to change because most times you won't use a database and people just put the listview index